# Shaking camera at large scene dimensions

Tags: rendering, animation, camera

We are currently working on a landscape scene in the size of 360x600 Km. The further away the camera (with animation of position and rotation) is from the world origin, the more inaccurate and jittery the result. It obviously makes no difference if it is a keyframe animation, driver or path animation. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Might be a [floating-point error mitigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_error_mitigation). The only workaround is to move the camera and the scene itself so that the camera is closer to the world origin.

Comment: Many thanks to you too! It's practically a confirmation of Mark's comments.

Comment: amazing tip. I was doing a "zoom" from space to earth on a building. (so pretty big scales). When i was getting closer to the building, everything started to shake. 
Thanks to this tip, I displaced the whole planet so that the building would be closer to 0,0,0. Everything is perfectly smooth now.

Answer (score 0):

Blender uses single precision floating point variables for coordinates. this means that while you can design locations even on scale of star systems, the precision drops as you move away from world origin. The smallest step of the floating point value from 10 is ~0.0000001, so on default settings, 10 meters away from the world origin the precision is a little bit below 1 µm.

In your case, 300 km (the larger dimension is 600 km, but I assume it's centered so it moves away from center only by 300 units) away from the world origin the precision is...

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> float(np.nextafter(np.float32(300_000), np.float32('inf')))
300000.03125
```

`0.03125` m or $3 {1\over8}$ cm. That's the steps the camera will inevitably have to do, since you can't set a float32 value to anything between 300'000 and 300'000.03125:

```py
>>> cam = D.objects['Camera']
>>> cam.location.x = 300_000
>>> cam.location
Vector((300000.0, 0.0, 0.0))

>>> cam.location.x = 300_000.02
>>> cam.location
Vector((300000.03125, 0.0, 0.0))
```

That's only the tip of the iceberg, however, as there's many calculations done behind the scenes that stack those inaccuracies. Therefore I'd advice trying to keep your camera values low (to further clarify, you should prioritize your camera location being low, over displayed objects' locations being low), which can be done in two ways:

- In [image] *Scene Settings > Units* Change *Unit Scale* to `1000`, and scale everything down also by `/1000`. For the scales you're working on, it should be enough. Yes, decreasing the values don't solve the precision problem in general, because both your location and your smallest step (precision) are multiplied by 1000. However, since more calculation is going on in regards to the camera, you moved the problem to where it hurts less - to the positions of objects and vertices. If you worked on microscopic you would want to do the reverse, change the *Unit Scale* to `0.001`, and scale everything up by a 1000.
- Keep your camera at the world origin and move the landscape instead. Divide the landscape into sectors, so that whenever you display something, the object containing it has small location values. This way the low precision will only affect objects that are far away from the camera.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed and well-founded answer! And it is indeed as you said. I moved the camera (along with the environment) near the world origin and the unsteadiness in the camera movement was gone immediately.

Besides just answering, I find the detailed description of the technical conditions that lead to the error really impressive!

This is significantly different here at Blender than for example at Autodesk...